# How can I register multiple custom post fields to json?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

sorry if this question has been asked before.

I have a few custom fields created with ACF and I am trying to push these fields to json, to use them in a js file.

My code looks like this:

```
function receiver_custom_fields() {
    foreach ( array('brand', 'name', 'cinema_dsp') as $field ) {
        register_rest_field( 'receiver', $field , array( 
            'get_callback' => function() {
                return get_field($field);
            }
        ));
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: field in
>   **E:\xampp\htdocs\test-comparator\wp-content\themes\hifi-compare\functions.php**
>   on line **8**

The fields: brand, name, and cinema_dsp are created.

I already created a function for each field and it works, but I want to add many more fields and I don't want to create a `register_rest_field()` function for each one.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$field` variable isn't available inside your `get_callback()` function. PHP isn't like JavaScript in that way, and that function can't access variables from outside its scope (unless it's `global`, but that's a poor solution).

To pass the `$field` variable through to the callback function, you need to write it like this:

```
'get_callback' => function() use ( $field ) {
    return get_field( $field );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jacob!